# Python measuring wind speed as a background process

Tags: python

Based on working code below designed to measure wind speed, two questions:

```
    import time
    import datetime
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    from statistics import mean
    
    # Initialization
    wind_tick = 0   # Used to count the number of times the wind speed input is triggered
    interval = 3    # Seconds to be waited between speed measurements
    mov_avg = 8    # Every 24 second average
    ws_readings = []
    samples = 0
    
    # Setup input GPIO pin
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    
    # Event to detect wind (4 ticks per revolution)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH) 
    
    def wind_trig(self):
        global wind_tick
        wind_tick += 1
        print(wind_tick)
    
    GPIO.add_event_callback(17, wind_trig)  
    
    try:
        while True:
            print(datetime.datetime.now())        
            time.sleep(interval)
            wind_speed = (wind_tick * 1.2) / interval
            wind_tick = 0
            ws_readings.append(round(wind_speed, 2))
            samples +=1
            if len(ws_readings) == mov_avg: 
                avg_wind_speed = round(mean(ws_readings),2) # averaging over 8 sample of 3 second wind
                gust_speed = round(max(ws_readings),2)
                print(ws_readings)
                ws_readings.pop(0)
                print(avg_wind_speed, gust_speed)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

**Questions:**

1. Infinite Loop

Measuring the speed must be done in a While True loop (reed magnet / anemometer). Problem is that in main.py I have to do other things such as measure other sensor, query sqlite3 and transmit data over a GSM module, while speed is measured continuously. If I import the module containing the code above (wind_speed.py) it obviously won't get past the import. I though about multi processing, queue or sockets (wind-speed to tx data to a server on same raspberry) but would like to hear your opinion.

2. If I package the code inside while True into a function it generates an error such as wind_tick referenced before assignment. I have to pass to get_wind_speed(wind_tick = wind_tick). is there a more elegant way to deal with it?

```
    def get_wind_speed():
        print(datetime.datetime.now())        
        time.sleep(interval)
        wind_speed = (wind_tick * 1.2) / interval
        wind_tick = 0
        ws_readings.append(round(wind_speed, 2))
        samples +=1
        if len(ws_readings) == mov_avg: 
            avg_wind_speed = round(mean(ws_readings),2) # averaging over 8 sample of 3 second wind
            gust_speed = round(max(ws_readings),2)
            print(ws_readings)
            ws_readings.pop(0)
        return avg_wind_speed, gust_speed
```

Comment: 1.) Measure the wind in a thread, that something like lightweight multiprocessing. Or look at asyncio, with a timer. Could also be a fine option. Are you measuring based on a timer or based on a interupt from the sensor? 2.) You could define it before, outside of the function then it is visible inside. Or pass it. In general, both are valid ways.

Comment: I am measuring based on a interrupt which calls a callback function (wind_trig):
GPIO.add_event_callback(17, wind_trig)

Comment: Then have a look at asyncio. It's a quite powerful module and should handle your case with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the loop in a thread. Multiprocessing wont give you any advantage over threading. Multiprocessing is meant for cpu bound tasks, while your loop is sleeping almost all the time, so doesn't make sense to use multiprocessing.

Moreover, with threading you have access to the same data from any thread, so you can directly read the data generated by the loop from the main thread without problem.

For the second question, to assign global variables inside a function you must declare them as globals:

```
global max_tick
```

But for a better code you should use a class:

```
class Wind:
    interval = 3   # constants
    ...

    def __init__(self):
        self.wind_tick = 0      #initialization
        self.ws_readings = [] 
        ...
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
        ...
        GPIO.add_event_callback(17, self.wind_trig)
        ...

    def wind_trig(self):
        self.wind_tick += 1
        print(self.wind_tick)

    def mainloop(self):
           while True:
               time.sleep(Wind.interval)
               self.wind_speed = (self.wind_tick * 1.2) / Wind.interval
               self.wind_tick = 0    
               self.ws_readings.append(...)
               self.samples += 1 
               ...
```

Now you can run the loop in a trhead:

```
wind = Wind()
thread = threading.Thread(target=wind.mainloop())
thread.start()
```